# Need to number each equation in an optimization problem

Tags: numbering, amsmath

I'm trying to number each equation in my optimization problem. I'm using `aligned`, which however, does not allow numbering.

Here is my code:

```
$\begin{aligned}
\max_{L_U} \quad & \Pi = m L_P - w_U L_U - w_P L_P\\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & m = \alpha_0 +  \alpha_1 L_U + \alpha_3\Omega\\
& w_P = \beta_0 + \beta_1 L_P  \\  
& w_U = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 L_U  \\ 
\end{aligned}$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use an `align` environment instead of an `aligned` environment.

I would also place the alignment points on the `=` symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align' environment
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\max_{L_U}  \quad  \Pi &= m L_P - w_U L_U - w_P L_P \\
\text{s.t.} \quad    m &= \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 L_U + \alpha_3\Omega \\
                   w_P &= \beta_0 + \beta_1 L_P  \\  
                   w_U &= \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 L_U 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a dedicated package that you can use: `optidef`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{optidef}

\begin{document}

\begin{maxi!}|s|%
{\strut L_U}%
 { \Pi= m L_P - w_U L_U - w_P L_P\label{objective}}%
{\label{optipb}}%
{}
\addConstraint{m}{= \alpha₀ + \alpha₁ L_U + \alpha₃Ω \label{constr-1}}
\addConstraint{ w_P}{= \beta₀ + \beta₁ L_P \label{constr-2}}
\addConstraint{w_U}{= \gamma₀ + \gamma₁ L_U \label{constr-3}}
\end{maxi!}

\end{document}
```

[image]